# Amplify - Federated Sign In - Failed to get user from user pool

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, federated-identity

I'm working on a `react-native` / `Expo` app using Amplify with Cognito for Authentication and Authorization.  I have configured Federated Sign On for Facebook and Google+ using the amplify CLI.

I am not using the hosted UI, I have created my own login interface with the respective buttons.

Here is the code for the Facebook Sign-In button:

```
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook'
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Alert } from 'react-native'
import core from '../../core'

export default () => {
    const handleFBSignIn = async () => {
        try {
            await Facebook.initializeAsync({
                appId: "##################"
            })
            const { type, token, expires } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync()
            if (type === 'success') {
                const { id, email, name } = await (await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}&fields=id,name,email`)).json()
                await Auth.federatedSignIn('facebook', { token, expires_at: expires }, { name, email })
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            await Alert.alert('Facebook Sign in Failed', ex.message, ['Ok'])
        }
    }


    return (
        <core.components.VisionButton
            title={<Fragment><FontAwesome name='facebook' size={16} color='#fff' /> Facebook</Fragment>}
            color='facebook'
            style={{ margin: 6 }}
            onPress={handleFBSignIn}
        />
    )
}
```

The call to `Auth.federatedSignIn(...)` succeeds and I get back a `FederatedUser`

`Hub` also receives an `auth` event for `signIn`

As far as the app is considered, there is now an authenticated user.  However, whenever I try to call any AWS resources that require authentication I get `No Current User`.

I have also noticed that, while the `Facebook` login is shown in the `Cognito Identity Pool`, no user is created in the `Cognito User Pool`.

How do I get a `CognitoUser` from a Federated Sign In?

Comment: The user gets automatically create when using the hosted UI. Since you are not using one there will be no user in to pool.

Comment: @AleksanderWons There must be a way to do it without the hosted UI?  I don't want users to leave the look and feel of my app.

Comment: There is none. But nothing really forces you to show the UI. The authorization endpoint of the hosted UI (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) allows you specify the provider you want. Then you never see the UI. Don't know how to configure it in Amplify but that's definitely possible.

Comment: @mcottingham did you find any solutions? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Amin no not yet.  I think there may be something to Aleksanders answer, but I haven't been able to get it to work yet.  I think it will work, but im missing something on either the FB configuration side, or maybe the Cognito configuration.  ‍♂️